# Completely stopping elasticsearch server and starting again, using java

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-java-api

I am working on Elastic search v-2.3.1. And i have added ReadOnlyRest plugin for Auth purpose.

To add users, i need to make changes in elasticsearch.yml, To add users in yml file i used snakeyaml from Java. successfully done.

Once the user is added to elasticsearch.yml, i need to stop and start the Elastic search server, so that new changes to yml file is read and Auth assigned to new users work.

I am able to do this manually, but i want to stop and start Elastic search from Java. if not Java API, rest will also work.

Please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There once was an API called `_shutdown` but it has [been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/breaking_20_removed_features.html#_literal__shutdown_literal_api) in 2.0.

You should now use the provided start/stop scripts in order to manage your ES cluster.

Comment: Actually i found out a way, I downloaded the ".deb" pack (Debian) of elastic search v-2.3.1. 

I can start the elasticsearch service with the below command.
"sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start"

Stop elasticsearch elasticsearch with the below command.
"sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop"

Made a shell script for this commands. and called from Java. Its working fine. 

There might be a better way but this way i was able to complete my requirement.

Comment: Yes, that's what start/stop scripts are for :)